# Prove that $f$ has a limit at infinity, provided that $|f(x)-f(x_n)| \leq 1/n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$, there exists $x_n$ such that $$|f(x)-f(x_n)| \leq \frac{1}{n}, \: \forall x>x_n$$
>   Prove that $f$ has a limit at infinity ( this limit may also be $\infty$)

I would like to know if my proof is correct. I did it by contradiction. Suppose that $f$ doesn't have a limit at infinity and let $a_n,b_n \to \infty$. Then let $l_1$ be a limit point of $(f(a_n))$ and $l_2$ be a limit point of $(f(b_n))$ such that $l_1 \neq l_2$. These limit points must exist, since otherwise $(f(a_n))$ and $f(b_n))$ would be convergent to the same limit. But $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ were randomly chosen, so this would mean that the limit of $f$ at infinity exists, contradiction.

Now, without loss of generality, suppose that the entire sequences $(f(a_n))$ an $(f(b_n))$ are convergent to these limits, since otherwise we could use another notation for their convergent subsequences. Since $a_n,b_n \to \infty$, there is $k_n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ such that $a_{k_n},b_{k_n}>x_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ and pick those numbers such that $k_{n+1}>k_n$. Hence $(a_{k_n})$ and $(b_{k_n})$ are subsequences of our sequences and moreover we have $|f(a_{k_n})-f(x_n)| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ and $|f(b_{k_n})-f(x_n)| \leq \frac{1}{n}$.

Taking limits when $n \to \infty$ in those inequalities gives $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}f(a_{k_n})=\lim_{n \to \infty}f(b_{k_n})=l_1=l_2$$
which is a contradiction. So $f$ must have a limit at infinity.

Comment: All the ideas necessary are there, it is just awkward and disorganized. And there is a case that is not covered: The case in which for all $a_n$, the sequence $f(a_n)\to+\infty$.

Comment: Well then $f$ would have a limit at infinity. I'll edit the statement to make it clear.

Comment: Is a limit of $\infty$ possible at all in this case?

Comment: One way to organize it could be this. Let $a_k\to\infty$ be an arbitrary sequence such that $f(a_k)$ is monotonic. If $f(a_k)$ is unbounded then one can pick $k$ large enough such that $a_k>x_n$ and $|f(a_k)|>|f(x_n)|+1$. Therefore, $1<|f(a_k)|-|f(x_n)|\leq |f(a_k)-f(x_n)|<1/n<1$ is a contradiction. Therefore, $f(a_k)$ should be bounded and therefore convergent. Now, for two such sequences the limits are the same because $|f(a_k)-f(b_k)|\leq |f(a_k)-f(x_n)|+|f(x_n)-f(b_k)|<2/n$ for $k$ large enough. Therefore, their limits are closer together than $2/n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Suggestion to simplify the proof: instead of having $a_n$ and $b_n$ be arbitrary, let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be subsequences for which $\lim f(a_n)=\lim\inf f(x)$ and $\lim f(b_n)=\lim\sup f(x)$. Then you can omit the first paragraph. Once you prove $\lim f(a_n)=\lim f(b_n)$, you immediately have $\lim f(x)$ exists.

Comment: Thanks everyone!